# Firebase Big Query: How can I see realtime data in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a Firebase application which is uploading events with parameters. I need to be able to view those events in order to debug some issues we're having in production. I can only see the tables which are generated nightly in BigQuery. I can find references online saying that BigQuery allows viewing real time data. What I can't find is any straightforward instructions on how to create those views.

Is it possible? If so, can someone give me instructions that even a complete newb could follow?

Comment: How to get the data uploaded in real time. I see events and their parameters in BigQuery but the tables are created nightly. that's way too slow for us.

Comment: According to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability) data should be available for real time analysis as soon as BQ acknowledges `tabledata.insertAll` request. In rare cases it might take ~ 2 hrs. What is the latency in your case?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan events transfer from analytics to bigquery in the middle of the night regardless of when they were uploaded. Note: I'm using firebase analytics, not the BigQuery APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have decided to use the BigQuery APIs for information we want to see immediately in the database.